# Given the video ID, how to get it's title using YouTube Data API v.3

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

In my project I generate custom wrappers for youtube video embeds on the client side. I used to get video titles by parsing xml responses from `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID`. Recently Youtube changed the title field for every video with "`https://youtube.com/devicesupport`" indicating deprecation of Data API v.2. I went to v.3 documentation and got confused. It was talking about authorization credentials, registering a project in the developers console, etc. Is it really necessary to just get a video's title?

Comment: I **was** using v2 but now i'm forced to use v3. It would be nice for them to keep the v2. It doesn't take long to register the application and get a key. You won't have to change much of your source code 'If it's only the title you want to get'. The advantage for you is that you can search multiple video ids (array) in one call. Do you have a specific problem or are you just asking for other peoples point of views. *If you have a specific problem can you display the source code you have and explain the issue.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only need a apikey of you application and videoID:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id%2Csnippet&id={video_id}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

Set the `part` parameter to `snippet` and `id` to the ID of the video. For example, with the ID `jofNR_WkoCE`, you will get:

```
{
 ...
 "items": [
  {
   ...
   "snippet": {
    ...
    "title": "Ylvis - The Fox (What Does The Fox Say?) [Official music video HD]",
    ...
   }
  }
 ]
}
```